# How can I retrieve argv[0] in a shell script?

Tags: shell, posix

I am currently trying to figure out how I can retrieve `argv[0]` inside of shell scripts.

The obvious answer would be to use `$0`, however it exhibits the following behavior:

```
# cat << EOF > /usr/local/bin/test-arg0.sh
> #!/bin/sh
> echo "ARG0 is '\$0'"
> EOF
# chmod +x /usr/local/bin/test-arg0.sh
# test-arg0.sh
ARG0 is '/usr/local/bin/test-arg0.sh'
```

Looking at an strace of the session above, I can see that the actual call to `execve` uses the short form for `$0`:

```
execve("/usr/local/bin/test-arg0.sh", ["test-arg0.sh"], ...)
```

So it seems like `/bin/sh` itself expands `argv[0]` to a full path when populating `$0`.

Is there any way I can retrieve the original `argv[0]` prior to expansion?

Comment: That's strange, i think it shouldn't happen. What `sh` implementation are you using?

Comment: If your `/bin/sh` does that to you -- do you need a *portable* answer, or does something that works only on Linux work?

Comment: The "expansion" seems to happen because you call the script from another directory.

Comment: https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/sh.html specifies: *Special parameter 0 (see Special Parameters) shall be set to the value of `command_file`. If `sh` is called using a synopsis form that omits `command_file`, special parameter 0 shall be set to the value of the first argument passed to `sh` from its parent (for example, `argv[0]` for a C program), which is normally a pathname used to execute the sh utility.*

Comment: ...so, as I read the spec, your `/bin/sh` is noncompliant, as what it's passing through is not the precise `argv[0]`; file a bug with its author.

Comment: Thank you all for your replies. I was also confused by this, as I was pretty sure never to have seen this behaviour int the past.

The shell is `GNU bash, version 5.0.7(1)-release-(x86_64-pc-linux-gnu)`.

I will compare it to behavior on other versions and possibly file a bug report.

Comment: `dash` seems to perform identically.

Comment: The interesting question would be, whether `sh` is really called using the synopsis with omitted `command_file`.
The only `execve` which I see in `strace -f` is the one I have posted as part of the question, but obviously the kernel recognizes the she-bang and executes `/bin/sh`, but also somehow tells it to run `/usr/local/bin/test-arg0.sh`. I am not sure how exactly this happens internally.